# strange recurrence relation and limit

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}$

$b_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_{n+1}b_{n}}$

also, $a_1=a$ and  $b_1=b$

can someone find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}$$ 
This question is from guillaume musso's novel. I remember that the answer included $\arccos$ thing..

Comment: [Which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume_Musso#Novels) novel, by the way?

Comment: @J.G. La Jeune Fille et la Nuit